# text-decoration problem in Firefox, jQuery and jqgrid

Tags: firefox, jqgrid, styles, word-wrap

I have issue wuth Firefox not displaying style "text-decoration: line-through".

I am using jqGrid for displaying list of medications. If medication is not active, it has to be crossed. In my afterInsertRow event I do this:

```
$('#' + rowid).css({ 'text-decoration': 'line-through', 'color': 'red' })
```

It works fine for IE and Chrome, but Firefox displays only red text without crossing line.

When I look into firebug output, I can see that `<tr>` element has style definition including text-decoration, but it is simply not displaying the way I need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you modify your code to

```
$('#' + ids[1] + " > td").css(
    { 'text-decoration': 'line-through', 'color': 'red' });
```

if will works. If you use `rownumbers: true` and don't want the row number be strikethrough, you can use

```
$('#' + ids[1] + " > td:not(.jqgrid-rownum)").css(
    { 'text-decoration': 'line-through', 'color': 'red' });
```

One more small recommendation: use `gridview: true` to fill jqGrid more quickly. In this mode the whole table contain will be filled by jqGrid as a siring and will be inserted with one `jQurey.append` operation. The usage of `afterInsertRow` event break the rule, because **every row** will be inserted with a `jQurey.append` operation and then will be called `afterInsertRow`. So my recommendation: use `gridview: true` and don't use `afterInsertRow`. To make changes of css use `loadComplete` or `gridComplete` instead like:

```
jQuery('#list').jqGrid({
    //...
    loadComplete: function() {
        var ids = jQuery('#list').getDataIDs();
        for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
            $('#' + ids[i] + ' > td:not(.jqgrid-rownum)').css(
                { 'text-decoration': 'line-through', 'color': 'red' });
        }
    }
    // ...
});
```

Comment: thank you for your detailed response. the reason why i am using afterInsertRow is that that my result set is not so big, and it will hold not more than 20-25 records, so i don't have to worry about the speed of loading.