# Jquery Grid problem

Tags: c#, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jqgrid

I have to create the Jquery Grid that have check boxes and drop down.

the requirement is that used can add now row to the grid and can update the existing row and there is Save Change button. So when user click on the save Change all the update go in one short.

How can i achieve this. do any one have example of that type of grid and scenario.

Please Help.

Thanks.

Comment: this is a really complicated explanation of your problem, what languages do you use to store the variables ? whar is your problem exactly, did you start on soemthing yet, or are you looking for information how to start ?

Comment: the requirement is when user click on the Add button the hidden field will add to save the data...and when click on the save change then update go in one short..

Comment: i have start using a grid pluging that use the XML to show the data..

Comment: All what you asked can be implemented, but your question is **too general** and have too many aspects. I doubt when somebody have already exactly the solution which you need. Moreover you don't wrote anything about the server part. Where you want save the data Microsoft SQL Server, MySQL or some other? Do you want use ASP.NET MVC, ASMX web services, WCF? Do you want (have to) to use JSON or XML? VS2008 or VS2010? Entity Framework, LINQ to SQL, SqlCommand/SqlDataReader? Stored Procedures or AdHoc SQL Queries? So you should better ask more specific technical question or an architecture question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at my slightly complex grid [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3530143/jqgrid-redrawing-is-slow). There is room for improvement, but it should help  a little.

If you make your data load locally, you can then ignore the update in the server after edit and when they press the save button (which you create yourself), iterate through all your rows and call the save method - `$("#Grid").jqGrid('saveRow', currentRowIterationID);`

You can add rows using $`("#Grid").addRowData(rowid,data, position, srcrowid);`

Have a look at [this](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods) page for a number of useful methods.

Answer (score 1):

I am doing just this at the moment, and after initially implementing jqGrid I have settled on SlickGrid since I have a large amount of data (both columns and rows) and the performance of SlickGrid is much better. I also really like the observer based programming pattern which is encouraged in the examples, however this is more of a personal preference rather than an objective one.

Here is the link to the demo page: http://wiki.github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/examples