# I want to set the style properties of the cell in treegrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-php, jqgrid-formatter

here is my code

```
jQuery("#tree").setCell (i,3,'',{"style='width':'18px'"});
```

and when i select the cell from firebug the cell looks like this:

```
<td aria-describedby="tree_name" title="task5" style="" role="gridcell">
  <div class="tree-wrap tree-wrap-ltr" style="width: 50px;">
    <div class="ui-icon ui-icon-radio-off tree-leaf treeclick" style="left: 36px;"></div>
  </div>
   <span class="cell-wrapperleaf">task5</span>
  </td>
```

i want to change the "width" of first "div" and "left" of second "div"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you use absolutely wrong syntax for the 4-th parameter of [setCell](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods) method. Instead of `{"style='width':'18px'"}` you should use `{width: '18px'}`:

```
$("#tree").jqGrid('setCell', i, 3, '', {width: '18px'});
```

The other part of your question about changing of the "width" and "left" seems be the wrong way how you try to change the **level** of the tree node. Every tree grid contains some hidden columns (`level`, `parent`, `isLeaf`, `expanded`, `loaded`) which values you should define together with the main data of the tree grid. The value from the hidden column `level` defines the position of the icon: the the "width" and "left" which you want to change.

Look at example from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7332627/315935) or [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6509041/315935) for details.