# JqGrid Load Json data from controller

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am using a jqgrid and i want to display the grid from the jquery a call to controller which return me json data my grid did not show the data code is here

```
public JsonResult GetPlainobjectAsJson()
        {
            var rows = (getdatalist()
                .Select(c => new
                {
                    id = c.CatId,
                    cell = new []
                                        {
                                            c.CatId.ToString(),
                                            c.CatName,
                                            c.desc,
                                            c.desc1,
                                            c.desc10,
                                            c.desc11,
                                            c.desc12,
                                            c.desc13,
                                            c.desc14,
                                            c.desc15,
                                            c.desc16,
                                            c.desc17,
                                            c.desc18,
                                            c.desc19,
                                            c.desc2,
                                            c.desc20,
                                            c.desc21,
                                            c.desc22,
                                            c.desc23,
                                            c.desc24,
                                            c.desc25,
                                            c.desc3,
                                            c.desc4,
                                            c.desc5,
                                            c.desc6,
                                            c.desc7,
                                            c.desc8,
                                            c.desc9,
                                            c.ProId.ToString(),
                                            c.ProName
                                        }
                })).ToArray();
            return new JsonResult
            {
                Data = new
                {
                    page = 1,
                    records = rows.Length,
                    rows,
                    total = 1
                }
            };

        }
```

this function generate the json data and this function

return the json result

```
  public JsonResult GetPlainobject()
        {

            var res = GetPlainobjectAsJson();

            return Json(res, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

and here is the index page

```
<script type="text/javascript">




    $(document).ready(function () {
        debugger;
        $("#treegrid").jqGrid({
            url: '@Url.Content("~/TreeGrid/GetPlainobject")',
            datatype: "json",
            mtype: "Get",
            colNames: ["CatId", "CatName", "desc", "desc1", "desc10", "desc11", "desc12", "desc13", "desc14", "desc15", "desc16", "desc17", "desc18",
                "desc19", "desc2", "desc20", "desc21", "desc22", "desc23", "desc24", "desc25", "desc3", "desc4", "desc5", "desc6",
                "desc7", "desc8", "desc9", "ProId", "ProName"],
            colModel: [
            { name: "CatId", index: "CatId", width: 150, key: true },
            { name: "CatName", index: "CatName", width: 200 },
            { name: "desc", index: "desc", width: 200 },
            { name: "desc1", index: "desc1", width: 300 },
            { name: "desc10", index: "desc10", width: 300 },
            { name: "desc11", index: "desc11", width: 150 },
            { name: "desc12", index: "desc12", width: 200 },
            { name: "desc13", index: "desc13", width: 300 },
            { name: "desc14", index: "desc14", width: 150 },
            { name: "desc15", index: "desc15", width: 200 },
            { name: "desc16", index: "desc16", width: 300 },
            { name: "desc17", index: "desc17", width: 150 },
            { name: "desc18", index: "desc18", width: 200 },
            { name: "desc19", index: "desc19", width: 300 },
            { name: "desc2", index: "desc2", width: 150 },
            { name: "desc20", index: "desc20", width: 150 },
            { name: "desc21", index: "desc21", width: 200 },
            { name: "desc22", index: "desc22", width: 300 },
            { name: "desc23", index: "desc23", width: 150 },
            { name: "desc24", index: "desc24", width: 200 },
            { name: "desc25", index: "desc25", width: 300 },
            { name: "desc3", index: "desc3", width: 200 },
            { name: "desc4", index: "desc4", width: 300 },
            { name: "desc5", index: "desc5", width: 150 },
            { name: "desc6", index: "desc6", width: 200 },
            { name: "desc7", index: "desc7", width: 300 },
            { name: "desc8", index: "desc8", width: 150 },
            { name: "desc9", index: "desc9", width: 200 },
            { name: "ProId", index: "ProId", width: 300 },
            { name: "ProName", index: "ProName", width: 150 }

            ],


            height: "auto",
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [10, 20, 30],
            pager:"#pager",
            gridview: true,
            viewrecords: true,
            caption: "Tree Grid Example",
            jsonReader : {
            root: "Data",
            page: "page",
            total: "total",
            records: "records"

            }

        });



    });

</script>
```

help me where i m wrong ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you should just remove unneeded `GetPlainobjectAsJson` method which return `JsonResult`. You should not use `JsonResult` as the parameter of `Json`. Instead of that you can include the code main code of `GetPlainobjectAsJson` inside of `GetPlainobject` and place

```
return Json(new {
                page = 1,
                records = rows.Length,
                rows,
                total = 1
            }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Additionally you should remove `jsonReader` from the client code and include `loadonce: true` instead. It will allow to use *local* sorting, paging and sorting/filtering of data in jqGrid. You can remove from `colModel` all `index` properties because there has the same values as `name` property.

Comment: thanks a lot dear but if i want to show data tree grid from this code where from i set the parent id

Comment: @zahaibzahaib: You are welcome! To fill TreeGrid you need fill not only the values for the main columns of grid but the values for some additional hidden columns which are created by TreeGrid and which describe the hierarchy of nodes/leafs. See [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5333199/315935) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6509041/315935) as examples. You can either load only top level nodes of grid and jqGrid will send additional request for cildren (see [the documentation]()http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:adjacency_model#what_we_post) or load all at once.

Comment: thanks dear but how can i add parent and level against a row because i m get data from the controller in json format which have catid as parent field and prodid as an child field how can i set these properties in controller code ... \

Comment: @zahaibzahaib: First of all you have to reorder the items which prepare the controller. First should come top level item then its direct children and so on. The order should corresponds the order in the TreeGrid when all nodes are opened. Then you have to add 5 additional items to `cell` array which represent every item. The additional items corresponds the values of hidden columns `level`, `parent`, `isLeaf`, `expanded` and `loaded`. Examine just JSON from [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6509041/315935).

Comment: THANKS A LOT oleg . but i m little confused how can i add new ceel in method GetPlainobjectAsJson() that have code above please ..

Comment: @zahaibzahaib: You create array with main data elements `cell = new [] {c.CatId.ToString(), c.CatName,..., c.ProName}`. It should contain *more values* which corresponds `level`, `parent`, `isLeaf`, `expanded` and `loaded`.