# Jqgrid custom format use bracket() if negatif value

Tags: php, javascript, jqgrid

Is any solution in **Jqgrid** if there is negative number then show bracket `"()"` ?

> ex: show (23) if value was -23

thanks

Comment: Please give some more detail about your issue.

Comment: `colNames:['Name','value'],
colModel :[
{name:'NAME', index:'NAME', width:20},
{name:'VALUE', index:'VALUE', width:15,align:'right',formatter: 'number',summaryType:'sum'},`   Ijust wan to display negatif number in bracket

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use custom formatter to do what you want. To format numbers or integers correctly you can call `$.fmatter.util.NumberFormat` method with `$.jgrid.formatter.number` or `$.jgrid.formatter.integer` as the second parameter. The example of the formetter is

```js
formatter: function (cellvalue, options) {
    var value = parseFloat(cellvalue), retult,
        op = $.extend({}, $.jgrid.formatter.number); // or $.jgrid.formatter.integer

    if(!$.fmatter.isUndefined(options.colModel.formatoptions)) {
        op = $.extend({}, op,options.colModel.formatoptions);
    }
    retult = $.fmatter.util.NumberFormat(Math.abs(value), op);
    return (value >= 0 ? retult : '(' + retult + ')') + ' €';
}
```

you can additionally change color or some other CSS style of displaying of the negative numbers. You can use `cellattr` property to add `class` or `style` attribute in the cells with negative numbers:

```js
cellattr: function (rowid, cellvalue) {
    return parseFloat(cellvalue) >= 0 ? '' : ' style="color:red;font-weight:bold;"'
}
```

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/FormatNegative.htm) demonstrate the settings. The results are the following

[image]

Comment: After change format of negative number . Is there any way is there to SUM that column in jqgrid to assign in same grid footer ? Because as per your code number will convert into string. So  $grid.jqGrid('getCol', 'columnname', false, 'sum') will return (nan).