# how can I change the color of footer data of jqgrid?

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-formatter

I have a jqgrid and on footer there are total values displaying. I want to convert the color of negative values to red. How can I do that?

Comment: which footer and summary you mean? Do you use grouping of you use just `footerrow: true`? How you fill the footer tow? Do you use `userDataOnFooter: true` option and calculates summary on the server or you use `userData` directly in the input? Probably you use `footerData` explicitly and makes some calculation with respect of `getCol` method? In any way you should describe more clear what you do.

Comment: yes i use footerrow: true and $("#gridId").jqGrid("footerData","set",dataArray); or 
$("#gridId").footerData("set",dataArray,true);
to set my dataArray to footer. then I want to color minus values on red color in footer data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `false` as the last parameter of `footerData` the data will be not formatted by jqGrid. So you can use HTML fragments like `<span style="color:red">...</span>` to change the color of displayed data. Alternatively you can use jQuery CSS Framework classes like `ui-state-error` to hightlight the text (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4943722/315935)).

If you need still format the summary value you can use `$.fmatter.util.NumberFormat` (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9664440/315935) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13703037/315935)) or use `formatter` method like in [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithTotalSum2.htm)

[image]

which uses

```js
footerrow: true,
loadComplete: function () {
    var $self = $(this),
        sum = $self.jqGrid("getCol", "amount", false, "sum"),
        i,
        iCol = $("#" + $.jgrid.jqID(this.id) + "_" + "amount")[0].cellIndex, // get index of "amount" column
        sumFormatted = this.formatter("", sum, iCol);

    $self.jqGrid(
        "footerData",
        "set",
        {
            invdate: "Total:",
            amount: sum < 0 ? "<span style='color:red'>" + sumFormatted + "</span>": sum
        },
        false
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I already have data array which is consist with all the column totals. What I want is, color minus total values using this  $("#gridId").jqGrid("footerData","set",dataArray,false);. Is there a way to do that.?

Comment: @DilanG: You are welcome! The data in `dataArray` can be **HTML fragments**. So you need just includes color formatting in the values of some properties of `dataArray`. I do the same in the demo which I posted in my answer.

Comment: sorry for disturbing you.But I didn't get u. In this demo u calculate the total of the in the function. But I already have calculated totals in array.The array structure is,
dataArray={"column1":total1,"colomn2":total2,....} like wise...
then how can I do this? can you show me please?

Comment: @DilanG: You should modify `dataArray` in the columns where you need have red color: `dataArray={"column1":total1 ? "<span style='color:red'>" + total1 + "</span>": total1,"colomn2":total2,....}`