# How to merge the footer row's column in jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a footer column, where i need to show the total information. I have added the footer row true and got the footer row added.

[image]

simlar to the above image.

Here in footer row, i want to merge the client and date colum for the total in single column.

Does any one have done, please share your thoughts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use my old demo from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19244741/315935). If I understand you correctly you want remove vertical lines (cell borders) between some columns in the footer row. One can set `colspan` (close to the results from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5625959/315935)). The disadvantage of the approach will be that one would need to adjust the `width` of the merged columns inside of `resizeStop`. So I suggest you to make unneeded vertical lines transparent. In general it's mostly the same what I described in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11792322/315935). In your case it would be something like

```js
var $footRow = $("#list").closest(".ui-jqgrid-bdiv")
                         .next(".ui-jqgrid-sdiv")
                         .find(".footrow");

$footRow.find('>td[aria-describedby="list_name"]')
    .css("border-right-color", "transparent");
```

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithTotalSum3.htm) demonstrates the approach. I made some more right borders of footer row invisible. So the results are like on the picture below:

[image]

Comment: Oleg, Thanks for the solution. But it would be really helpful if we have some options to merge the column in the jqgrid in footer row. May be some thing like setGroupHeader, we can create setGroupFooter for footer row also. Why i'm saying this is, in a bigger application, we might need to apply transparent style to each grid. I request you, in future enhancement, we can add this also. please suggest

Comment: @BabuArumugam: You are welcome! I can try to send the feature request to *developer* of jqGrid (to [trirand](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/feature-request/)). I posed a lot of bug fixes and code of some features (for examples `setGroupHeader`), but I'm not an official developer of jqGrid. Moreover you should understand, that answering on questions on the stackoverflow, writing bug reports and new features gives me no money. So I can spend for it only a part of my free time...

Comment: yes Oleg, i very well know that no one is paid for answering in Q&A sites and its merly intreset of the person who answers the question. I just only requested you since, you was one & only active contributter of the jqGrid and also answering the Q&A sites. Some time before, i have posted a issue about the "Disabled pager button", which you added the fix for that and now it was fixed in 4.5.6 version. So I thought you might atest. Thanks for the reply.