# How one can use colspan in the jqGrid footerData?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jqgrid

**Want to create the jqgrid footer as described in below grid:**

[image: Jqgrid footer row with merged row]

I want the footer in the jqgrid as shown in above jqGrid.
I have set the `footerrow:true` and  `$self.jqGrid("footerData", "set", { Total: actualSum });`, with this i am able to get the footerRow.
And to add label to this as i mentioned 'Grand Total: ' i need to merge two columns Amount and Tax..
So, how can achieve these.
I have gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5625325/how-to-merge-cells-in-jqgrid-4-0).
But the cellattr is used to merge the cells.. Incase of footer row i am not able to get this cellattr if there is way to use these approach. How can i fix my probelm using this?

I even gone through [these answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22190756/how-to-merge-the-footer-rows-column-in-jqgrid).
Here, just the the right border are made hidden conditionally but the colsapn is not used.
So that too didn't help me to fix my problem.

Currently i am getting the footer like these:
[image]

@Oleg can you just guide me how i can fix this issue and create the footer using the colspan as i described.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One can use `colspan` in the footer too. It's important to understand that jqGrid set the footer **once** during creating the grid and then just can change the width of columns on the footer if the user resized the column width.

To simplify the code I suggest to set `resizable: false` property on the columns where we use `colspan`. [The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithTotalSumColSpan.htm) demonstrates the solution:

[image]

In the demo I added `resizable: false` property in "Client" and "Date" columns ("name" and "invdate" columns) and used the following code *after* jqGrid is created:

```
var $footRow = $("#list").closest(".ui-jqgrid-bdiv").next(".ui-jqgrid-sdiv").find(".footrow");

var $name = $footRow.find('>td[aria-describedby="list_name"]'),
    $invdate = $footRow.find('>td[aria-describedby="list_invdate"]'),
    width2 = $name.width() + $invdate.outerWidth();
$invdate.css("display", "none");
$name.attr("colspan", "2").width(width2);

$footRow.find('>td[aria-describedby="list_tax"]').css("border-right-color", "transparent");
$footRow.find('>td[aria-describedby="list_total"]').css("border-right-color", "transparent");
$footRow.find('>td[aria-describedby="list_closed"]').css("border-right-color", "transparent");
$footRow.find('>td[aria-describedby="list_ship_via"]').css("border-right-color", "transparent");
```

Comment: Thanks.. @Oleg
For background color i made some changes...
But it worked for me

Comment: Just one question in your example...  
`$name.width() + $invdate.outerWidth()` 
Why you are using width() and outerWidth() two different properties to retrive the columns width?

Comment: @Rekha: cells of grid have some borders which will be calculated by `.outerWidth()`. So I need to increase the width (without of border etc.) of visible cell with the **full width** of all cells which I make hidden. In the case the total `width` of new cell will have correct value.