# jqGrid Search returns blank for the first time only for dynamically populated columns

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a jqGrid where JSON data comes from server and I convert it to local data type later.
Last column is populated with data, once all other data is loaded from server based on certain conditions. like

```
 if ((cmgName.substr(-1) === "1") || (cmgName.substr(-1) === "2"))
                $('#list').setCell(rowId, "Compliance", "Yes", {background: '#00FF00'});
```

While search works fine for other columns, it returns blank for last column for the first time. 
i.e. if I search for "No", at first it returns blank (0 records). After resetting, if I search for "No". grid returns correct results.

How do I ensure it works correctly for the first time as well. Is it related to creating index over the column or refreshing data?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you need to set the background color of `Compliance` column based on the input data then I would recommend you to define `cellattr` callback in the column. It allows you to set additional `class`, `style`, `title` or any other attributes on the column based on the input data of the cell or based on content of other columns of the row. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12180842/315935), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6048865/315935) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9664440/315935) as an example. One can combine `cellattr` with formatters. Thus you can for example display checkboxes (`formatter: "checkbox"`) or `"Yes"`/`"No"` textes (`formatter: "select"`) or any other independent from setting the color or background color of the cells of the column.

Comment: it is about deciding the value and not just background color. Issue I see is, no response from search in case of search bar.

Comment: @MalTec: You should include **much more information about what you do**. How the column `Compliance` is defined? Which `datatype` you use? Do you use `loadonce: true` or not? Which format have input data you have? Which version of jqGrid you use?