# How to add background color to a jQgrid row based on value of a column?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

This piece of code i am trying to add background color to jqgrid but no luck yet.
Please someone help me to improve my code.Thanku in advance.

```
function (data) 
{
    var rowData = $("#grdTimeReport").getDataIDs();

    for (var i = 0; i < rowData.length; i++) 
    {
        if (data[i].rowData.ProdNonPro== "NP")
        {
            $("#grdTimeReport").jqGrid('setRowData', rowData[i], false, 'myclass');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting the data correctly from grid?

Comment: Yeah!!! there is no problem in getting the data.

Comment: Try this=>http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4028019/set-class-or-identifier-on-jqgrid-row-based-on-a-key-value-pair-placed-in-row-l

Comment: Hey!!!! Thank you so much.. It worked..:) :)